# Equivalent of strace -feopen < command > on mac os X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dtrace, strace

This is useful for debugging (hence programming related).  On linux, we can use the command

```
strace -feopen python myfile.py
```

to figure out which python modules and shared objects are loaded.  Is there an equivalent one-liner on macOS X?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

I suppose you meant `strace -fetrace=open`?

```
dtruss -f -t open python myfile.py
```

Comment: Hi ephemient, I just tested your version of strace (with -fetrace=open) and it gave exactly the same outuput as my example.  I look forward to testing your dtruss command shortly. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Somehow, today, sudo dtruss doesn't work for me. It's as if Python is not executed at all!

Comment: @qarma sudo-ing back again might solve your problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/215510/enable-dtrace-without-sudo-on-mac-os-x/215531#215531

Comment: btw., some `open` calls are reported as `open_nocancel` on osx. same wrt. `read` and `read_nocancel`.

Comment: btw., some `open` calls are reported as `open_nocancel` on osx. same wrt. `read` `recv` `close` and perhaps a bunch/all others, they seems to have `*_nocancel` counterparts.

Comment: `dtruss` requires root privileges, but you might not want to run the command you want traced as root. Consider `sudo dtruss -f -t open sudo -u $USER python myfile.py`

Comment: The link to `dtruss` in your answer is broken.

Comment: @michaelbahr Apparently Apple moved their manpages to `/legacy/` now.

Comment: Getting an error with `$ sudo dtruss -f -t open sudo -u $USER python`: `
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available` and then `dtrace: failed to execute sudo: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements`

Comment: The only way to run `dtruss` as an `strace`/`ltrace` replacement on macOS (since roughly 2018) is to disable SIP through `csrutil disable` in recovery mode. It's unfortunate, especially if one only needs it for a quick session to see which files are opened by process or similar query tasks.