# git-svn not working, reporting "fatal: cannot exec 'git-svn': Not a directory"

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to migrate an svn repo to git. but i am stucked at

```
git svn clone https://svn.xxx.com/repos/xxx/trunk ~/temp
```

which throws a "fatal: cannot exec 'git-svn': Not a directory" error

say i'm in directory ~/temp, even i run just "git svn", I got the same error message.

tried

```
man git-svn
```

works well.

What's the problem please?

Comment: you need to give path to the original svn repo

Comment: is it a repos url or a file path? I tried both git svn clone https://svn.xxx.com/repos/xxx ~/temp and file:///Sites/xxx (my local svn repo) ~/temp.  still the same error

Comment: what's your OS, how did you install git?

Comment: MAC OSX SL, git should be installed by following github's instructions

Comment: It's related to your PATH, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4110132/11343)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that answer. but i do have the root access on my local machine. and the git version is 1.7.2.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11048/discussion-between-charlesb-and-jinzhao-huo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing these, problem seemed gone. and i got a new version git 1.7.3.4, not sure whether it was a problem of version 1.7.2

```
sudo port deactivate git-core
sudo port install git-core +svn
```

Refer to http://redlinesoftware.com/blog/2008/2/24/converting-subversion-repositories-to-git

**But my git-svn and git-svnimport are busted!** section

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use SubGit project ([subgit.com](http://subgit.com)) for migration. It preserves the most important SVN concepts (EOLs, ignores, tags, merges and so on) much better than git-svn. And also it keeps in sync SVN and Git repository so you can use both SVN and Git interfaces until you run

```
subgit uninstall <path/to/svn/repo>
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. we'll drop SVN once we've git settled :)