# git aws.push command not created by eb init

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, deploying

I was following the tutorial on [how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application on AWS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) and got the following error when trying to execute the `git aws.push` command:

`fatal: cannot exec 'git-aws.push': Not a directory`

According to [this tutorial](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git) the `eb init` was supposed to have created this new git command for me, but apparently it did not... Has someone stumbled upon this problem? How can I fix this?

I am using Mac OS Lion.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked my .git/config file, and guess all the aliases are there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019501/git-alias-problem) to solve my problem. Check if there is no folder to which you don't have the necessary permissions or files in your PATH.

Answer (score 21):

I was running into the same issue and there seems to be a small issue currently with the installer of the tools working on a non bash implementation.

Here's the fix (as relayed to me via Amazon) 
use the command:

```
 $ bash path/to/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

***bash*** here replaces ***sh*** which was shown in the tutorial(s) and it then worked for me

Comment: After this, in some cases, you might get an error "Module BOTO doesn't exist". Then, use "sudo pip install boto".

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:<path to unzipped EB CLI package>/eb/linux/python2.7/
```

Comment: this is standard procedures for eb setup, without this eb will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, make sure you have run:

```
AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat
```

AND

```
AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.bat
```

These batch files setup the git interaction with EB and the AWS CLI.