# Uploading files from a Cyrillic path using pycurl

Tags: python, unicode, pycurl

I've recently designed an upload dialog backed by PyCURL which I'm using in a few of my applications.
I have run into an issue when setting pycurl's HTTPPOST option. I am setting it like so:
    self.curl.setopt(self.curl.HTTPPOST, [(field, (self.curl.FORM_FILE, filename))])
If filename is a string, all is fine. If I pass it a unicode, however, it raises a TypeError.
Is there any way for me to be able to give it a Cyrillic path? I tried UTF-8 encoding it, but that was unsuccessful.
Thank you for your time

Update:

I'm actually getting the filename from a WX control, so it's unicode before I even touch it. When I then encode it to UTF-8, (using filename = filename.encode('UTF-8')) the setopt goes fine but everything blows up on perform:

```
* About to connect() to example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 123.123.123.123... * connected
* Connected to example.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
* failed creating formpost data
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\transfer_dialogs-0.28-py2.7.egg\transfer_dialogs\transfer_dialogs.py", line 64, in perform_transfer
    self.curl.perform()
error: (26, 'failed creating formpost data')
```

Update 2:

As requested, a bit more data.  filename contains the result of a GetValue() from the open dialog.
    logging.debug("Filename: %r encoded filename: %r" % (filename, filename.encode('UTF-8')))
result:
    Sat Feb 05, 2011 03:33:56 core.dialogs.upload_audio DEBUG: Filename: u'C:\Users\Q\test\\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0430\u043f\u043a\u0430\test.mp3' encoded filename: 'C:\Users\Q\test\\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\test.mp3'

Comment: "I tried UTF-8 encoding it, but that was unsuccessful" -- explain HOW you tried, and what was the outcome: gibberish, exception (traceback would help), other). Also: what is a "Cyrillic path"?? A filename/path encoded in e.g. cp1251? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I tried with filename = filename.encode('UTF-8').  The line which set the HTTPPOST option then raised: error: (26, 'failed creating formpost data')  OS Windows. The path is something like: r"C:\Users\Q\test\Тестовая папка\test.mp3"

Comment: Instead of `something_like(filename)`, please use `repr()` to show unambiguously the unicode filename that you got from the wx control.

Comment: @John As requested:
    logging.debug("Filename: %r encoded filename: %r" % (filename, filename.encode('UTF-8')))
result:
    Sat Feb 05, 2011 03:33:56 core.dialogs.upload_audio DEBUG: Filename: u'C:\\Users\\Q\\test\\\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0430\u043f\u043a\u0430\\test.mp3' encoded filename: 'C:\\Users\\Q\\test\\\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\\test.mp3'

Comment: Thanks. No weird chars; only ASCII and Cyrillic. Things to try: write a small stand-alone script that attempts to open the filename 3 times (as unicode, encoded as UTF, encoded as cp1251). What is the "ANSI" encoding on your system? Note that there's a space in the filename. Can the app handle a filename with ASCII characters and a space? Are you sure that the name of the actual file on disk is as received from the wx control?

Answer (score 0):

Filename should be in UTF-8, *and* the host you upload it to should support UTF-8 file names. If it supports a different, non-Unicode encoding, try to encode the filename KOI8-R or WIN1251 (but this, of course, is not nice and standards-compliant).

**EDIT**, having seen the comments: Probably it should have been  `ur"C:\Users\Q\test\Тестовая папка\test.mp3".encode("UTF-8")`. That `u` bit it important; without it, the Cyrillic letters are taken encoded in your console encoding. I did just try it, and it worked (not upload, just `setopt`).

Comment: When I encode the filename as UTF-8 I get: error: (26, 'failed creating formpost data')  witth the HTTPPOST line.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose this problem into 2 components:

1. tell pycurl which file to open to read file data
2. send filename in correct encoding to the server

These may or may not be same encodings.

For 1, use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` to convert unicode filename (which you use throughout python code correctly) to a string that pycurl/libcurl can open correctly with `fopen()`. Use `strace` (linux) or equivalent [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows) [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925978/equivalent-of-strace-feopen-command-on-mac-os-x) to verify correct file path is being opened by pycurl.

If that totally fails you can always feed file data stream from Python via `pycurl.READFUNCTION`.

For 2, learn how filename is transmitted during file upload, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work). I don't have a good link, all I know it's not trivial, e.g. when it comes to very long file names.