# How to read file data from CURL param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, sinatra

In my sinatra application, I am using following `curl` command to post a file in route `/test`.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -vv -X POST -d file_data=@test.xml 
        http://localhost:4567/test
```

At my Sinatra post method I want read file like

```
post '/test' do

   data = params[:file_data] #Here file_data param name of CURL command.
end
```

But, here `data` is `NULL`. How should I configure my CURL command to read file from `file_data` param ?

Comment: You should use `--data-binary @test.xml`  - check this out http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary

Comment: @PamioSolanky, doesn't work. Still I can't read file from file_data param.

Comment: If you just want to `POST` the file then you can use this instead `curl  -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -i -F name=test -F file_data=@localfile.jpg http://localhost:4567/test`

Answer (score 0):

curl -F file_data=@/some/file/on/your/local/disk `http://localhost:4567/test`

from cURL manual:

```
-F, --form <name=content>
```

(HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.

for more details: [cURL manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Quick answer*: Remove `-H "Content-Type: text/xml"` and it should work.

The problem is that when a file is sent, the `Content-Type` header should be `multipart/form-data`, which `curl` sets automatically when you use `-F`. From [`curl`s documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F):

> -F, --form 
>                 (HTTP)  This  lets  curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit
>                 button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc.

However, you are overwriting this header with `-H`, so your app is expecting something that is not a file.

If, in addition to sending the file with `curl`, you want to include information about its type, you should instead do this:

```
curl -X POST -F "file_data=@test.xml;type=text/xml" http://localhost:4567/test
```

(The content type comes after the file name and a semicolon.)

To see how a raw form submission request ends up looking like with `multipart/form-data`, check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8659808/4183217).