# Upload file to box error

Tags: upload, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to upload a file to box based on the api here: https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file, and I always get a "**bad request**" error.

Where is the problem?

url =  `https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content`
data = `{"name":"1.jpg","parent":{"id":"0"}}`

```
        private Stream postToUrl(string url, string data)
        {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken); 
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            return dataStream;
        }
```

I also tried to use the url: `https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content?access_token=AccessToken`
instead of the Token inside the header

Comment: Where are you specifying the required `name` and `parent` attributes?

Comment: Outside of the function, I wrote the exact values that I get in "data" and "url" parameters. The file name is "1.jpg", and I'm uploading it to the root folder (id=0).

Comment: I do it that way: "{\"name\":\"" + fileName + "\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"" + destinationFolderId + "\"}}"

Comment: Sorry, then where is your function reading and submitting the actual file data?

Comment: @tufelkinder I want to get a stream and then fill it outside. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe the file data and attributes need to be submitted simultaneously as part of the multipart request. See Greg's answer below. An SDK should save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2):

File uploads should be a multipart request, but it looks like your body is JSON. I also don't see where you're setting the file's content.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660740/108) gives a good example of what a multipart request should look like. The easiest solution is to either use the SDK or find a library that can create a multipart request for you.