# MultiValueDict is empty when image has loaded

Tags: python, django, httplib

I'm trying to simulate browser work. When I'm sending image from browser I get in request.FILES that

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

If I send image from back end POST request:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST, PORT)
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",      "Accept": 'text/plain', 
"Cookie": cookies, 'X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
conn.request("POST", "/upload/%s" % storyId, open("pictures/1.jpg"), headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

I get:

```
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a file from broswer, the `Content Type` header is `multipart/form-data`; not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` also  there are others changes in the request when you send a file. Take a look, here is how a request headers looks like when you send a file from a browser.

```
POST /upload?upload_progress_id=12344 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Length: 1325
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
<other headers>

------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

100000
------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="hello.o"
Content-Type: application/x-object

<file data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L--
```

You can read more here in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)

Said that, you aren't "simulating" a browser file request correctly.