# HTTP file upload without form

Tags: http, file-upload

I was wondering if I can upload a file to the web server by passing the file as string of bytes in the URL. I know this is possible for other form elements by using the syntax:

```
www.example.com\index.php?user="user"&pass="pass"..etc
```

If it's possible, what is the format of the byte string?

Answer (score 1):

## Can files be uploaded without HTML forms?

In *theory*, sure. HTML forms allowing file uploads usually make a browser perform a `POST` query. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work) for some details.) Servers usually don't care how that query was created on the client side. (If they want to care, they must implement [cross-site request forgery prevention measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention).)

Thus in *practice*, this depends on your client: If it can construct the `POST` request without the form, you're set.

## Can files be uploaded as URL parameters instead of in the body of `POST` requests?

In *theory*, yes, if they aren't too large. (URLs are limited in length.) Nothing in the HTTP protocol forbids you to do that.

In *practice*, there is probably no established convention on how to do this, so your client **and** your server will have to feature some custom implementation for this and to agree on the encoding etc.

Thus *you* can decide the format of the encoded string (as long as it's allowed within an URL parameter), but *you* would probably also have to implement that format on either side.