# How can I see submitted POST request data in Chrome DevTools for multipart/form-data

Tags: http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a web app, and I see a POST operation I'm interested in.  It's a post with Content-Type multipart/form-data, which according to the headers has Content-Length 875.  This is (Chrome 71.0.3578.98)

But chrome is not displaying any Request-Payload.  See the images below.

Other posts with different Content-Type, e.g. text/xml do display the Request-Payload as a section.

(1) Is the Request-Payload not displayed BECAUSE this is multipart/form-data and would sometimes be large files (it's not, only 875 bytes).

(2) Is there any way to see the Request Payload in this case?

```
Request Headers
```

[image: POST Request Headers]

```
Collapsed headers, showing no Request Payload
```

[image: POst request]

Comment: I have the same issue on ubuntu using chrome.  Firefox does show it under Params.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains that Chrome devs made this decision for "performance reasons" and there is no way to disable it.  The linked answer is from 2018, but this seems to still be the case on Chrome 77.  It would be reasonable to open an issue for Chrome to: consider the size before hiding, and at least list the post data field (and indicate it is hidden).  Some other Don Quixote can try creating that issue... :-)

Comment: @Marvin The linked duplicate is slightly different from this one. In that link, F12 dev tools in some older Chrome does show Form data, except that the content of uploaded file is hidden for performance reasons. But what this question describes is that Chrome (71.0.3578.98) does not even show any form fields, whether they are regular form fields or uploaded files. My own testing confirms that this problem remains in Chrome 79.0.3945.130: if a file is uploaded, Chrome hides all Form data (including regular form fields). If no file is uploaded in a multipart form, Chrome does show all form data.