# How can i see the request data of a django form submit in Chrome?

Tags: python, django

I want to see the request payload but all i see is the request and response headers in the dev tools network tab.

A similar question is asked here but with no answer.
[How can I see submitted POST request data in Chrome DevTools for multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409184/how-can-i-see-submitted-post-request-data-in-chrome-devtools-for-multipart-form)

Can someone please tell me how i can see the request and response payload of a django form submit? thank you

Comment: This might help https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger

Answer (score 1):

Below the "General", "Request Headers" and "Response Headers" you should see the "Form Data".

[image: See my screenshot here]