# How to see form data with enctype = "multipart/form-data" in Chrome debugger

Tags: google-chrome, http-post, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to visualize form data in Chrome Debugger. Data are sent through a from which loads a file and sends some text. Something like this one:

```
<form action="url" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="file" name="file"> <br>
     <input type="text" name="some_text">
</form>
```

If I explore the headers of the POST request with dev tools, I do not see form data section but I just find:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXGBFWL5ab6g5XoFN
```

that, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321259/4820341) is a kind of separator used to segregate data. However, I do not see anything else about submitted data.

How can I see actual data about the filed `some_text` in Chrome Debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a "multipart/form-data" POST request actually contain a string with the data of an uploaded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174658/should-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-actually-contain-a-string-with-the-d)

Comment: Are you sure it is the same problem? I wouldn't like to mark this question as solved if it is a different issue. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: I am pretty confident it is the same problem. Did you follow the link in the answer with 2 upvotes? Google Chrome's engineers acknowledge that this is by design:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/FaInquBDhU0

"8/9/15
 Andrey Kosyakov Please file this on crbug.com -- this is due to limitations of current design, as we send post data instantly to the front-end and don't want huge file uploads to thrash the front-end."

Comment: Already read this 4-year-old response but I’m not sure that it is still valid respect to the current Chrome version. Besides, If I remeber well, also other small values are not displayed in the request tab. If you had other details to help us figure this out, please extend your answer below.

Comment: I am sure the problem still exists with current chrome version 77 and 78, since I am having the problem right now, which is the reason why I found your question. Also yesterday I confirmed that Fiddler is showing the body of the post request correctly. There is no realistic way I will find an updated statement of a Chrome engineer stating that this is still current design. I can confirm that showing the content of an entire 800 KB file in Fiddler's GUI makes it lag like hell (at least on my PC), so it is logical that this is still the reason why Chrome does not display it.

Comment: What about the rest of the form?

Comment: The rest of the form is hidden by chrome, for the reason already mentioned. You can report it as a bug to Chrome if you want.

Answer (score 46):

I tested on my platform: Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10. I confirm that this problem remains on the up to date version of Chrome (as of 1/22/2020).

To be precise, the problem I found in Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (and Chromium Edge 79.0.309.68 as well) is as follows:

1. For a multipart/form-data POST request, if we don't specify any file to upload and hit the form submit button, we do see the "Form Data" section under Network tool's headers tab. The "Form Data" section lists all regular form fields, e.g., a form field <input type="text" name="title" value="hello Chrome"/> is shown in the following pic, and the file field shows nothing because I didn't upload any file.

[image]

2. For a multipart/form-data POST request, if we actually upload a file, regardless of its size (such as 0B), the entire "Form Data" section disappears, including regular form fields! See the following pic in which I collapsed all sections under Headers to demonstrate the point.

[image]

I agree it makes good sense to hide the file content for performance reasons as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174658/should-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-actually-contain-a-string-with-the-d) and this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/FaInquBDhU0), but it makes no sense to hide all regular form fields as well. I believe this is a Chrome bug.

In FireFox, we see all Form Data and uploaded file content under F12 dev tools > Network > Params. In the following example, I uploaded file.txt with the content: hello Firefox from file.txt.

[image]

So Firefox offers a temporary solution before Chrome addresses this issue.

Comment: 2021 says Hi, and Chrome form debugging is still broken.

Comment: Still broken in 2022.

Comment: And Firefox may have removed the "Params" tab now. Fabulous. (I don't see it, anyway.)

Comment: Firefox has "Request" tab now

Comment: 2023, Chrome making a hit streak ... Version 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 6):

The problem still exists with chrome versions 77 and 78. It is working with tools like Fiddler.

See the answers to this question: [Should a "multipart/form-data" POST request actually contain a string with the data of an uploaded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174658/should-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-actually-contain-a-string-with-the-d)

They suggest to use Fiddler. Chrome developer tools do not show the data, because the developers chose not to for performance reason and acknowledge this is a limitation of current design.

See also this Chrome bug [report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1019710&q=multipart%2Fform-data&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: Are really Chrome Dev Tools supposed not to show anything? Even `<input type="text" name="some_text">` data? Where can we read more about this?

Comment: @floatingpurr I added the relevant Chrome's bug report.

Answer (score -3):

Just looking at the Headers tab in the Network tab in chrome dev tools shows me the entered data (Chrome Version 73):

[image: Picture of the request with headers in chrome dev tools]

Keep in mind that in order for requests to show up in the Network tab you have to open the chrome devtools before the request happens.

Comment: I do not see the form data section in my case

Comment: You see the "Form Data" section only when you don't submit a file at all, if you are using multipart/form-data enctype. See my answer for more details.