# Should server return error page or render form again on 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, http, error-handling, http-status-code-400

I have a basic web app (not api) with pages and forms. If a user sends a for e.g. register form with values that cannot be validated, I render the form page again with [status 422](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329229/should-i-return-an-http-400-bad-request-status-if-a-parameter-is-syntactically) indicating where faulty inputs were made.

**When the syntax however is wrongly formed, should an error page be displayed to the user with the code 400 Bad request, or should it render the register form page again with a message saying that the request body was malformed (response still 400)?**

My thoughts:
Arguments for error page: It seems that there is something wrong with the frontend (client) if it sends POST requests without or with a wrong body. Either the frontend has to be fixed, or the request body was manipulated. This should never happen* if the user sent the form normally and the frontend is not faulty.

*Why I doubt: I’m not 100% sure that it's impossible that it could be a temporary error of the client or maybe a network issue or something else. If this is plausible, then the user has to be redirected to the form again with the info that the request body was wrong. He should be able to try again.
My related question basically is this: is it possible that in the normal flow of actions the server receives a request with a faulty body?

Answer (score 0):

> it’s a mistake to try to map each part of your application “deeply” into HTTP status codes; in most cases the level of granularity you want to be aiming for is much coarser. When in doubt, it’s OK to use the generic status codes 200 OK, 400 Bad Request and 500 Internal Service Error when there isn’t a better fit.

422 vs 400 goes down to a granular level, and these codes are often times for developers rather than end users (unless your end users are developers). This helps you to go through the logs and figure out what the heck actually happened. If there is an error on the form I would just render a validation message for users indicating that something went wrong, or you could go into more details with validations.

You could use something like Sentry that will provide the stack trace of the actual error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question wasn't about 422 vs 400 at all. I am talking about body syntax malformed (not wrong inputs from users). The question before my question is: **Is it possible that in the normal flow of actions the server receives a request with a malformed body syntax?** like is that an error that "could happen" from time to time (then I would render the form) or does it always mean that something is wrong (then I would render the error page so that the user reports the bug)

Comment: Oh my bad, gotcha, this could definitely happen, for instance if you are trying to create an entry, for which there is unique index in the database. For instance the email already exists it should return 400/422 request because it was unable to process it. Also if you are for instance enforcing a ruleset on a field(i.e. enforcing a validation that no links may be present within the message from the back-end) it should throw 400/422. It can happen yes. Should you redirect to a bug reporting page? If there is no restriction or validation on your form, it should not throw those errors...

Comment: Yeah, for all sorts of validation errors (name too short, invalid email etc.) I return 422 and tell the user exactly where he made which mistake.
A malformed body syntax is for instance when I expect the argument "email" in the body but it was not given.
Validation error: "email: $dfdf@$$.com" 
Wrong syntax: "emai: anything@test.com" or "em: email@adsf.com" or nothing

Comment: You can observe this if you follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59871612/9013718 and w3 wants 400 to be returned if not the values but the "keys" or "arguments"  or idk how to call them are not valid for the server. The server can't "understand" the request as it doesn't contain the needed keys to evaluate the content.