# How to send the content of v-file-input?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My component is something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-file-input accept="image/*" v-model="image"></v-file-input>
    <button @click="uploadImage">Upload</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      image: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async uploadImage(){
      await this.$axios.put('url', {image: this.image})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I click the button and send the request, the request payload is `{image: {}}`. Why? How to send the content of `this.image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a `POST` rather than a `PUT`. But your code is working: if you `console.log(this.image)`, you'll see the file, same goes for your Vue devtools in your browser.

I'm not sure how to see it in the network tab but this is properly sent to the given backend. I guess you just need a proper backend here.

This question may be useful here: [How to see form data with enctype = "multipart/form-data" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55743964/8816585)

Here is an MDN page talking about `multipart/form-data` objects even if there is no solution on how to see the actual payload neither: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1):

Just send file with FormData. You can put this code into uploadImage():

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append(file, this.file);
this.$axios.post('url', form)
```

And then U can access it in server.

Answer (score 0):

here try this code pen i made
[codepen v-file-input](https://codepen.io/adammuse/pen/XWRMwWe?editors=1011)

```
        addImage (file) {
        if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const imgObj = new Image()
      // console.log(e.target.result)
      imgObj.src = e.target.result
      // console.log(imgObj)
      this.imageHandler = imgObj
    }
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
   } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
  }
```

major take aways:

```
const reader = new FileReader()

const imgObj = new Image()

imgObj.src = e.target.result
```

then reasign `this.imageHandler = imgObj`