# Uploading images with fetch to Express using Multer

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, upload, multer

I'm attempting to upload images to an Express server. I'm not exactly sure about how to do this, but heres what I've got from what I've been able to pick up from MDN, `express`, `react-dropzone`, and `multer` Documentation. Multer does not seem to pick up the FormData object from `react-dropzone`, when logging out `req.file` it returns undefined.

#### server.js

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './public/users',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            switch (file.mimetype) {
                case 'image/jpeg':
                    ext = '.jpeg';
                    break;
                case 'image/png':
                    ext = '.png';
                    break;
            }
            cb(null, file.originalname + ext);
        }
    });

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.use(upload.single('photo'));

app.post('/uploadUserImage', function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.photo)) // form fields
    console.log(req.photo) // form files
    console.log(req.file) // form files
    res.send(req.body.photo);
});
```

#### client.js

```js
    function uploadImage (image) {
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('photo', image);
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/uploadUserImage/', {
        method:'POST',
         body: formData
      });
    }
```

When I make this request `morgan` logs out the following:

{ photo: '[object File]' }   <--- from console.log(req.body');

undefined                    <--- from console.log(req.file);

`multer` creates the folder `public/uploads` but does not place the image in the location. How can I get the photo because I need to run it through [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) (to compress the filesize and resize the image) and then place it in the `uploads` folder?

Answer (score 12):

The error occurs because you specified the `'Content-type'` explicitly. To do this properly, you'd also need to specify the boundary. You can find a detailed explanation of `multipart/form-data` here: [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)

To solve the issue with the file upload, you should remove the `'Content-Type'` specification from the `fetch` request. You can also refactor the `uploadImage` method to upload the form without parsing the inputs:

```
function uploadImage () {
  // This assumes the form's name is `myForm`
  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/uploadUserImage', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. The image should be in your `uploadUserImage` directory in your server.

Comment: It worked for me, but you should mention that the input's name must match the multer's config `upload.single('photo')` `'photo'` in this case

Answer (score -1):

The problem for me was that firebase has an error and can't use multer. You need to use busboy and parse it manually. Also I needed to append the uri from react native imagePicker instead of the file blob. Like this:

```
data.append('fileData', {
  uri : pickerResponse.uri,
  type: pickerResponse.type,
  name: pickerResponse.fileName
});
```