# PHP Upload - how to get the relative path of an uploaded file?

Tags: php, file-upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have my videos in a folder on my desktop:

```
/home/john/Desktop/Samples/Vids/small.mp4
```

How can I get this file path from upload or other ways?

This is my html form:

```
<form class="form-submission" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload[]" id="input-file" multiple required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default no-gradient">Submit</button>
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => small.mp4
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => video/mp4
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/php1KNwas
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 383631
                )

        )

)
```

But there is no info of the path - `/home/john/Desktop/Samples/Vids/small.mp4`

Any ideas how can I get it?

I need to find the video file path so I can send it to my youtube channel:

```
// REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
$videoPath = "/home/john/Desktop/Samples/Vids/small.mp4";

....

$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


// Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
  $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}
```

The entire video uploading code is from [google's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video).

Comment: You don't need the client real path. You have the file (server side) -> /tmp/php1KNwas !

Comment: Plus the client does not send it, as you can see if you dump the HTTP headers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work#8660740 for an example dump. And even Jascript does not let you access this via the input attributes. So this seems impossible to me.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I need the path bcos PHP upload won't let me upload any video more than 7MB in the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini...

Comment: So you need it in order to access the file directly on your disk !! This is not possible. Either you change the 'upload_max_filesize' or you enter the file path manually, assuming you are on the same machine without any access restrictions !

Comment: Aww ok. I think I have to `enter the file path manually`! Thanks for the help!