# Uploading files using Vapor

Tags: vapor

I've seen in documentation in [Body section](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/body.html) that there's a support for file uploading right now - or at least I understand it this way

I have no strong *foundation* in backend development - especially if it comes to frameworks which are still eveloving so fast as Vapor do. 
I wonder if someone can provide some real life example of file uploading? I was hoping for a simple web page with possibility to upload a file to the backend and then store it for future usage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vapor allows for file upload using the Multipart encoding. You can read more about HTTP upload here:

[How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)

And also here:

[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

So the HTML code to upload a file to Vapor would look something like:

```
<form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then the code in Vapor

```
drop.get("form") { req in
    return try drop.view("form.html")
}

drop.post("upload") { req in
    let name = req.data["name"]
    let image = req.data["image"] // or req.multipart["image"]

    ...
}
```

In terms of how to store the image, that is up to you. You can store in a database or create a folder on the system to which you have write access.

Comment: is there any demo out there with image storing example?

Comment: @tanner0101 is it same in vapor 2 also?