# file upload using Vapor

Tags: swift, file-upload, vapor

I can't find any example of handling file upload, especially how to save into some specific folder.

Here is the code, addVideo is a HTTP POST multipart/form-data:

```
videos.post("addVideo") { req in

    // need to save req.multipart["video"] into /data/videos/

    return try JSON(node: ["status": 0, "message": "success"])
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988329/uploading-files-using-vapor

Answer (score 3):

example look like this：

vapor 2.0 server code:

```
let d =drop.grouped("file");
d.post("updateFile") { req in
  let data = Data.init(bytes: (req.data["image"]?.bytes)!)
  let picName = req.data["name"]?.string ?? String();
  try Data(data).write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/xx/Desktop/\(picName).jpg"))
  return try JSON(node: ["status": 0, "message": "success"])
}
```

Client code:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image", fileName: "pic", mimeType:"image/jpg")

        multipartFormData.append("picName".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "name")

    }, to: "http://0.0.0.0:8083/file/updateFile") { (encodingResult) in

        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this example, but we figured out already how this works. Anyway, my main concern here is that you creating Data instance from file's bytes. This means that you load file bytes into memory. Imagine that you uploaded video - so you constructing Data from received bytes, loading in memory, which takes time and ram. What I'm looking is some way to just save into file without loading into memory, like just writing to handle.

Comment: Did you find a better solution? @ValeriiLider

Answer (score 2):

From your `Multipart.File` get the `Bytes` and convert to `Data`.

```
guard let file = request.multipart?["video"]?.file else {
  return "Not found"
}
try Data(file.data).write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/data/videos/FILENAME"))
```

You can get FILENAME from the `File` object or make your own.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but: is there a way to save bytes to file without creating Data object? For big files it takes time till it performs, but I only need to save to file system

Comment: do you know who to get the absolute path (with the host) of the file? I get something like file:///path/to/folder which is okay but I want to have https://myapp.herokuapp.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: For me neither `let d = Data(req.data as? Primitive)` nor `let d = Data(req.body.bytes)` works. Why?

Answer (score 1):

While other answers explained how to save data as file, the following code shows how to save data as database blob:

```
guard 
    let name = request.data["filename"]?.string, 
    let blob = request.data["file"]?.bytes
else {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Fields 'filename' and/or 'file' is invalid")
}
let user = try request.user()
let image = try Image(filename: name, user: user, file: blob)
try image.save()
```