# Scrapy upload file

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am making a form request to a website using scrapy. The form requires to upload a pdf file, How can we do it in Scrapy. I am trying this like -

```
FormRequest(url,callback=self.parseSearchResponse,method="POST",formdata={'filename':'abc.xyz','file':'path to file/abc.xyz'})
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida - I think it is not solving the purpose,, I mean the file is not being uploaded by the code snipplet I provided, it is taking the path as "STRING" (I want it to take it as a file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spent an entire day trying to figure out how to implement this.
Finally, I came upon a Scrapy [pull request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1954/files) from 2016 that was never merged, with an implementation of a multipart form request:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin, urlencode
import lxml.html
from parsel.selector import create_root_node
import six
import string
import random
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes, is_listlike
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url


class MultipartFormRequest(FormRequest):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formdata = kwargs.pop('formdata', None)

        kwargs.setdefault('method', 'POST')

        super(MultipartFormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        content_type = self.headers.setdefault(b'Content-Type', [b'multipart/form-data'])[0]
        method = kwargs.get('method').upper()
        if formdata and method == 'POST' and content_type == b'multipart/form-data':
            items = formdata.items() if isinstance(formdata, dict) else formdata
            self._boundary = ''

            # encode the data using multipart spec
            self._boundary = to_bytes(''.join(
                random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters) for i in range(20)), self.encoding)
            self.headers[b'Content-Type'] = b'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + self._boundary
            request_data = _multpart_encode(items, self._boundary, self.encoding)
            self._set_body(request_data)


class MultipartFile(object):

    def __init__(self, name, content, mimetype='application/octet-stream'):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
        self.mimetype = mimetype


def _get_form_url(form, url):
    if url is None:
        return urljoin(form.base_url, form.action)
    return urljoin(form.base_url, url)


def _urlencode(seq, enc):
    values = [(to_bytes(k, enc), to_bytes(v, enc))
              for k, vs in seq
              for v in (vs if is_listlike(vs) else [vs])]
    return urlencode(values, doseq=1)


def _multpart_encode(items, boundary, enc):
    body = []

    for name, value in items:
        body.append(b'--' + boundary)
        if isinstance(value, MultipartFile):
            file_name = value.name
            content = value.content
            content_type = value.mimetype

            body.append(
                b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + to_bytes(name, enc) + b'"; filename="' + to_bytes(file_name,
                                                                                                              enc) + b'"')
            body.append(b'Content-Type: ' + to_bytes(content_type, enc))
            body.append(b'')
            body.append(to_bytes(content, enc))
        else:
            body.append(b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + to_bytes(name, enc) + b'"')
            body.append(b'')
            body.append(to_bytes(value, enc))

    body.append(b'--' + boundary + b'--')
    return b'\r\n'.join(body)


def _get_form(response, formname, formid, formnumber, formxpath):
    """Find the form element """
    root = create_root_node(response.text, lxml.html.HTMLParser,
                            base_url=get_base_url(response))
    forms = root.xpath('//form')
    if not forms:
        raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)

    if formname is not None:
        f = root.xpath('//form[@name="%s"]' % formname)
        if f:
            return f[0]

    if formid is not None:
        f = root.xpath('//form[@id="%s"]' % formid)
        if f:
            return f[0]

    # Get form element from xpath, if not found, go up
    if formxpath is not None:
        nodes = root.xpath(formxpath)
        if nodes:
            el = nodes[0]
            while True:
                if el.tag == 'form':
                    return el
                el = el.getparent()
                if el is None:
                    break
        encoded = formxpath if six.PY3 else formxpath.encode('unicode_escape')
        raise ValueError('No <form> element found with %s' % encoded)

    # If we get here, it means that either formname was None
    # or invalid
    if formnumber is not None:
        try:
            form = forms[formnumber]
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("Form number %d not found in %s" %
                             (formnumber, response))
        else:
            return form


def _get_inputs(form, formdata, dont_click, clickdata, response):
    try:
        formdata = dict(formdata or ())
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise ValueError('formdata should be a dict or iterable of tuples')

    inputs = form.xpath('descendant::textarea'
                        '|descendant::select'
                        '|descendant::input[not(@type) or @type['
                        ' not(re:test(., "^(?:submit|image|reset)$", "i"))'
                        ' and (../@checked or'
                        '  not(re:test(., "^(?:checkbox|radio)$", "i")))]]',
                        namespaces={
                            "re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
    values = [(k, u'' if v is None else v)
              for k, v in (_value(e) for e in inputs)
              if k and k not in formdata]

    if not dont_click:
        clickable = _get_clickable(clickdata, form)
        if clickable and clickable[0] not in formdata and not clickable[0] is None:
            values.append(clickable)

    values.extend(formdata.items())
    return values


def _value(ele):
    n = ele.name
    v = ele.value
    if ele.tag == 'select':
        return _select_value(ele, n, v)
    return n, v


def _select_value(ele, n, v):
    multiple = ele.multiple
    if v is None and not multiple:
        # Match browser behaviour on simple select tag without options selected
        # And for select tags wihout options
        o = ele.value_options
        return (n, o[0]) if o else (None, None)
    elif v is not None and multiple:
        # This is a workround to bug in lxml fixed 2.3.1
        # fix https://github.com/lxml/lxml/commit/57f49eed82068a20da3db8f1b18ae00c1bab8b12#L1L1139
        selected_options = ele.xpath('.//option[@selected]')
        v = [(o.get('value') or o.text or u'').strip() for o in selected_options]
    return n, v


def _get_clickable(clickdata, form):
    """
    Returns the clickable element specified in clickdata,
    if the latter is given. If not, it returns the first
    clickable element found
    """
    clickables = [
        el for el in form.xpath(
            'descendant::*[(self::input or self::button)'
            ' and re:test(@type, "^submit$", "i")]'
            '|descendant::button[not(@type)]',
            namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
    ]
    if not clickables:
        return

    # If we don't have clickdata, we just use the first clickable element
    if clickdata is None:
        el = clickables[0]
        return (el.get('name'), el.get('value') or '')

    # If clickdata is given, we compare it to the clickable elements to find a
    # match. We first look to see if the number is specified in clickdata,
    # because that uniquely identifies the element
    nr = clickdata.get('nr', None)
    if nr is not None:
        try:
            el = list(form.inputs)[nr]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            return (el.get('name'), el.get('value') or '')

    # We didn't find it, so now we build an XPath expression out of the other
    # arguments, because they can be used as such
    xpath = u'.//*' + \
            u''.join(u'[@%s="%s"]' % c for c in six.iteritems(clickdata))
    el = form.xpath(xpath)
    if len(el) == 1:
        return (el[0].get('name'), el[0].get('value') or '')
    elif len(el) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Multiple elements found (%r) matching the criteria "
                         "in clickdata: %r" % (el, clickdata))
    else:
        raise ValueError('No clickable element matching clickdata: %r' % (clickdata,))
```

This is the code I used to call the request (in my case I needed to upload an image):

```
with open(img_path, 'rb') as file:
    img = file.read()
    file_name = os.path.basename(img_path)
    multipart_file = MultipartFile(file_name, img, "image/png")
    form_data = {
        "param": "value", # this is an example of a text parameter
        "PicUpload": multipart_file
    }
    yield MultipartFormRequest(url=upload_url, formdata=form_data,
                               callback=self.my_callback)
```

It's a shame that so much time has passed and Scrapy still doesn't have a built in way to do this, especially since someone wrote a very simple implementation years ago.

Answer (score 3):

At this very moment Scrapy has no built-in support for uploading files.

File uploading via forms in HTTP was specified in [RFC1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867). According to the spec, an HTTP request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` is required (in your code it would be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

To achieve file uploading with Scrapy, you would need to:

1. Get familiar with the basic concepts of HTTP file uploading.
2. Start with `scrapy.Request` (instead of `FormRequest`).
3. Give it a proper `Content-Type` header value.
4. Build the request body yourself.

See also: [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)