# Upload captcha image with Scrapy Request

Tags: python, http, post, scrapy, recaptcha

Im trying to solve a captcha using `2Captcha.com` service. First I'm saving the captcha image:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(captcha_image_link, 'captcha.jpg')
```

Next I need to upload the image to the server to recognize it. Using plain requests its just as simple as

```
files = {'file': open('captcha.jpg', 'rb')}
payload = {'key': TWOCAPTCHA_APIKEY, 'method': 'post'}
request = requests.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php', files=files, data=payload)
```

But how to make the same request with Scrapy? I mean, how to attach an image file to a POST Request? Is this possible? If not, then I would like to know whether its too bad idea to use plain POST request (and urlretrieve as well) inside a Scrapy spider or not?

Comment: Why must you make the request with scrapy. In this case you just want the response of the solved captcha so the next request can be made. So `import requests`

Comment: I just want to clarify it for myself - Is it safe and correct to use `requests` inside a Scrapy spider? Would plain request slow it down?

Comment: It might do. You can read this interesting article but I can't speak on whether it is `right` or `wrong`: http://www.scrapinginsider.com/2016/01/scrapy-urllib2-requests-beautifulsoup-lxml.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Though that article offers me to scrape the website with BS and requests running in some threads - which is not that Im looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303851/scrapy-upload-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can send POST request using Scrapy (see [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)), but there are two things to consider:

1. You would have to encode the files yourself while `requests.post` does this for you.
2. Scrapy would send the request asynchronously, which is probably not what you want when you need to solve captcha.

Thus, I see nothing wrong using your current aproach inside Scrapy spider.