# Translating Requests request to Scrapy request

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

[image]

I'm working on an ocr project using scrapy using the ocr api at https://ocr.space/ocrapi . I have some code that works successfully using requests:

```
        file_string = ctypes.string_at(image_data_pointer, length.value)

        payload_filename = 'my_hires_image.jpg'
        # Post payload as multipart encoded image file with filename.
        # requests.post(THE_URL, files={'file': (payload_filename, payload)})

        payload = {'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
                   'apikey': api_key,
                   'language': language,

        r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
                          files={payload_filename: file_string},
                          data=payload,
                          )
        return r.content.decode()
```

I'm now trying to turn this into a scrapy post request. I have:

```
payload_filename = 'my_hires_image.jpg'
# Post payload as multipart encoded image file with filename.
# requests.post(THE_URL, files={'file': (payload_filename, payload)})

body = {'file': file_string,
        'isOverlayRequired': True,
           'apikey': 'mykey',
           'language': 'eng',
           }

files = {payload_filename: file_string}

yield FormRequest(url='https://api.ocr.space/parse/image', headers=headers2,  formdata=body, callback=self.ocr_space, meta={'row': row, 'cookiejar': i}, dont_filter=True)
```

please note that file_string is a byte string. You can see it in screenshot above. The code is giving me:

```
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "Emy_PROject/spiders\ocr_spider.py", line 148, in get_PDF
    yield FormRequest(url='https://api.ocr.space/parse/image', headers=headers2,  body=body, callback=self.ocr_space, meta={'row': row, 'cookiejar': i}, dont_filter=True)
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(FormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 26, in __init__
    self._set_body(body)
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 69, in _set_body
    self._body = to_bytes(body, self.encoding)
  File "/\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 117, in to_bytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got dict
```

How can I get this working?

edit:

```
body = {'files':file_string,
        'isOverlayRequired': True,
           'apikey': '*******',
           'language': 'eng',
           }

body = urllib.parse.urlencode(body)

x = FormRequest('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image', headers=headers2,  formdata=body, callback=self.ocr_space, meta={'row': row, 'cookiejar': i}, dont_filter=True)
```

yields:

```
  File "....\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "....\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "....\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "....\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "....\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "myproject\spiders\ocr_spider.py", line 151, in get_PDF
    x = FormRequest('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image', headers=headers2,  formdata=body, callback=self.ocr_space, meta={'row': row, 'cookiejar': i}, dont_filter=True)
  File "....\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 31, in __init__
    querystr = _urlencode(items, self.encoding)
  File "....\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 66, in _urlencode
    for k, vs in seq
  File "....\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    values = [(to_bytes(k, enc), to_bytes(v, enc))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: how about `body = urllib.parse.urlencode(body)`

Comment: or maybe check parameters in documentation [FormRequest](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest)

Comment: I tried your suggestion , but it gives:   File scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    values = [(to_bytes(k, enc), to_bytes(v, enc))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). Also according to the Formrequest docs you can pass a dic as formdata.

Comment: if you can pass dictionary as `formdata=` so why you pass it as `body=` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I tried it as both, the error is the same.

Comment: as for new error - you could put it in question with exacly code which you used.

Comment: `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).` it seems you use something different than dictionary,

Comment: please see edit:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303851/scrapy-upload-file. It appears there may be no direct support for file upload in scrapy.