# Upload plugin to WordPress using scrapy

Tags: python, wordpress, scrapy, python-requests

I'm trying to upload WordPress plugin using scrapy. I'm able to log in and navigate to choose the file path but I'm unable to see file path passing in upload request. Probably it's opening and sending file content but I'm also unable to crack that too.

Here's code what I have tried yet:

```
yield Request(
                url=f'{TARGET_WEBSITE_HOST}/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin',
                method='POST',
                callback=self.upload_plugin,
                meta={'upload-step': 2},
                headers = {} # Need to pass file here probably?
            )
```

Comment: It is not necessary to answer the question, but could you add a psotscript explaining why you want to use Scrapy for this? It’s an unusual use case :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303851/scrapy-upload-file)

Comment: Nope, because specifically, Wordpress doesn't show anything going in the request.