# Trigger PHP's input parser

Tags: php

For good or for bad I have made the decision to use a custom (out of spec) HTTP method in my project. Now PHP is not parsing my request's body because the method is not "POST".

I know I can parse the input myself using `php://input` and `parse_str` but there are also `multipart/form-data` requests that I do not know how to parse and would like to avoid having to deal with.

Is there any way I can trigger PHP's internal request body parser manually when the request is not `POST`?

Comment: this would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work

Comment: Would `$_REQUEST` work?