# Uploading files to Azure via web Api throws Unsupported Media type exception?

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload files to azure through browser using Web Api and angular, I've followed this example:
https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/07/upload-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-web-api/

I send the request from angular service (not sure if this is the right implementation!):

```
this.PostFiles = function (files) {
    var req = $http.post('/api/GENAccounts/UploadFile', files);
    return req;
}
```

and the `files` is an array of files selected by the user

```
<input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files, $invalidFiles)" multiple accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="3MB" />
```

I even followed the same test described in the article by passing simple string via Postman, and it still throw the same error, and always this statement return `true`

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }
```

In his implementation, he doesn't define the object POSTed in the web api which is unusual behavior to me. So how to pass the files to web API, and in any format that can pass this `form-data` test?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have followed the code example you provided to build my Web API, I could make it work as expected on my side. When using Postman to test, you need to set content-type to `form-data` and data type to `file` as follows:

[image]

Based on your JavaScript code, you are using [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) to upload your file(s) while `Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent` receives the specified content `multipart/form-data` in your Web API back-end.

Per my understanding, for a simple way, you could leverage `Upload.upload()` for `multipart/form-data` upload cross browser as follows:

**HTML**

```html
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" ngf-multiple="true" ng-model="files" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="3MB"/>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```html
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, Upload) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/GENAccounts/UploadFile',
                    data: { file: file }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
                }, function (resp) {
                    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                }, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Note:** For more detailed samples, you could follow the usage samples from [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Additionally, you need to change the `_supportedMimeTypes` [MiME Types](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) within the `AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.cs` as follows:

`private readonly string[] _supportedMimeTypes = { "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg" };`

Also, there is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work) talking about how does Http file upload work, you could refer to it.