# Send a file via POST using Dart (server-side only)

Tags: file-upload, dart, server-side

I am developing a Telegram Bot, and I need to send a file via POST as attachment to an user (e.g. a .txt file). Upon this, I have two questions:

- Which file type should I use in order to send a file? I heard about
  Stream, but I am unsure about it;
- Having the right file type, how can    I send it as a parameter for
  the url POST? I tried the http library    and built-in solutions.

  Here is a snippet of the code I'm using right now:

  ```
  Future<dynamic> sendRequest(String method, url, {json}) async {
      BaseClient bs = new IOClient();
      var request = new Request(method, url);
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      request.body = JSON.encode(json);
      var streamedResponse = await bs.send(request);
      var response = await Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

      var bodyJson;
      try {
        bodyJson = JSON.decode(response.body);
      } on FormatException {
        var contentType = response.headers['content-type'];
        if (contentType != null && !contentType.contains('application/json')) {
          throw new Exception(
              'Returned value was not JSON. Did the uri end with ".json"?');
        }
        rethrow;
      }

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        if (bodyJson is Map) {
          var error = bodyJson['error'];
          if (error != null) {
            throw error;
          }
        }
        throw bodyJson;
      }

      return bodyJson;
  }
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: What format is the data to be sent? Is it always text based? What size is the data? I assume you are reading it from a file, but is it short enough that you can reasonably read it into a string?

Comment: I have many situations: the file can be an audio, a video, etc. Let's say I have a .mp4 file sized 5MB. In this case, how can I submit the file via POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer that you are using the Dart Pub `http` package. Briefly looking at the documentation it appears that both *multi part* and *streaming* uploads are supported. See the `MultipartRequest` and `StreamedRequest` classes. (I have not used these myself but they seem straightforward.)

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B9/http/http-library.html

This question may help with understanding HTTP `multipart/form-data` file uploads. [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work). Others may be able to point to a good resource on streaming uploads.

Comment: I am still facing many problems whit file uploading, but your answer helped me a lot. Thank you.