# Upload image to Shopify using Python and REST API

Tags: python, rest, post, request, shopify

I have read through the Shopify API documentation for how to insert an image to Shopify from here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-image

I have the following code, which can successfully connect to Shopify and retrieve images associated with a product:

```
import requests

# Connect to Shopify
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@store.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s/products/5161320611973/images.json" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, API_VERSION)

# Get data
data = requests.get(shop_url)
```

This works successfully, Now I would like to upload a new image to a product.
This is the code I am using:

```
# Create image data
imgdata = {
  "image": {
    "src": "https://pkmncards.com/wp-content/uploads/en_US-CP-079-charizard_v.jpg"
  }
}

# POST image data to Shopify
x = requests.post(shop_url, data = imgdata)
```

This gives the following result:

```
<Response [400]>
{'errors': {'image': 'expected String to be a Hash'}}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what mistake I may have made?

Answer (score 1):

Using `json` instead of `data` in the requests should do the trick:

```
# POST image data to Shopify
x = requests.post(shop_url, json = imgdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading images to Shopify is hard work, I've just finished a working uploader here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77412107/22669764](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43511573/22669764) which would will get the image onto Shopify (make sure your API has file read/write permissions).

I'm not using it to add images to products at present, but the script will give you the shopify ID for the uploaded image i.e. `gid://shopify/ImageSource/1234567890` from there you should be able to use that to attach it to your products.

Hope that helps

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments I'm adding the working code from my answer on the other page in case that disappears for any reason.

This will allow you to upload an image into the `files` section on Shopify, wait 10 seconds, then performs a final query to pull the URL out of Shopify. The 10 second wait is needed because I found that the API will sometimes not grab data if it's just created, it slows things down but it's better than erroring out.

**EDIT #2:** Updated the url retrieval query to use `id` rather than `created_at` at, fixes weird glitch where Shopify selects an older random image.

```
import requests
import os
from time import sleep

# Set up Shopify API credentials
shopify_store = 'url-goes-here.myshopify.com' // the actual URL is here
access_token = 'token-goes-here' // the actual token is here

# Read the image file
image_path = r'C:\the-actual-filepath-is-here\API-TEST-1.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image file
with open(image_path, 'rb') as file:
    image_data = file.read()

# Create staged upload
staged_upload_url = f"https://{shopify_store}/admin/api/2023-04/graphql.json"
staged_upload_query = '''
    mutation stagedUploadsCreate($input: [StagedUploadInput!]!) {
        stagedUploadsCreate(input: $input) {
            stagedTargets {
            resourceUrl
            url
            parameters {
                name
                value
            }
            }
            userErrors {
            field
            message
            }
        }
    }
'''
staged_upload_variables = {
    "input": [
        {
            "filename": filename,
            "httpMethod": "PUT",
            "mimeType": mimetype,
            "resource": "IMAGE"
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(
    staged_upload_url,
    json={"query": staged_upload_query, "variables": staged_upload_variables},
    headers={"X-Shopify-Access-Token": access_token}
)

data = response.json()
staged_targets = data['data']['stagedUploadsCreate']['stagedTargets']
target = staged_targets[0]
params = target['parameters']
url = target['url']
resource_url = target['resourceUrl']

############  START NEW CODE ############
# Post image data to the staged target
headers = {
    param['name']: param['value'] for param in params  # Fix the headers assignment
}
image_length = len(image_data) # We need this in a couple of places
headers["Content-Length"] = str(image_length)
req = requests.Request('PUT', url, headers)       
prepped = req.prepare()
try:
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
        prepped.body = f.read(image_length)
        s = requests.Session()  
        r = s.send(prepped, stream=True)
    print ('File sent OK')
except Exception as error:
    print (f'File send error: {error}')  

############  END NEW CODE ############          

# Create the file in Shopify using the resource URL
create_file_url = f"https://{shopify_store}/admin/api/2023-04/graphql.json"
create_file_query = '''
mutation fileCreate($files: [FileCreateInput!]!) {
fileCreate(files: $files) {
    files {
    alt
    createdAt
    fileStatus
    ... on MediaImage {
            id
            image {
            url
            height
            width
            }
        }
    }
    userErrors {
    field
    message
    }
}
}
'''
create_file_variables = {
    "files": [
        {
            "alt": "alt-tag",
            "contentType": "IMAGE",
            "originalSource": resource_url
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(
    create_file_url,
    json={"query": create_file_query, "variables": create_file_variables},
    headers={"X-Shopify-Access-Token": access_token}
)

data = response.json()
files = data['data']['fileCreate']['files']
alt = files[0]['alt']
id = files[0]['id'].split('gid://shopify/MediaImage/')[1] # We only need the number

############  GET IMAGE URL ############
# Adapted from https://community.shopify.com/c/graphql-basics-and/file-api-get-the-file-url-after-it-s-being-uploaded-successfully/m-p/1445697/highlight/true#M903
sleep(10) # Give GraphQL a chance to show results
find_img = '''query {
    files (first: 1, query:"id:\'%(id)s\'") {
        edges {
        node {
            ... on MediaImage {
            image {
                id
                url
                altText
                height
                width
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}''' % {'id': id}
find_img = requests.post(staged_upload_url,json={"query": find_img},headers={"X-Shopify-Access-Token": access_token})
find_img_data = find_img.json()
############  END GET IMAGE URL ############

print(data)
print(find_img_data)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. If you think this question is a duplicate of another, you can flag it as such. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35220254)

Comment: Hi @dan1st,  it's not really a duplicate as this question asks more about linking the image to a product. I can add my fully working code here which would give OP and others a working example to build upon.