# How file upload send the image file (in which form)?

Tags: android, http

When I load the file using type = "file" 
it selected any extension from the folder. 
then my question is 'how this file formed to send it to other  server or page?'

```
 <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

let say I selected the file    image.jpg. 
how this image.jpg transformed? 
and where they stored? 

and how they send this file?

I'm asking this question because 
Im using webview on android 
when I access to the android gallery file it retuned some bitmap format.
I want to know how to send this bitmap format on

```
 <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Binary files will be converted into text by the browser. This will be happen by using base64. Then the browser put this converted file into response header and as last step starts the transmission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)

Comment: Where the file is stored is dependent on many things, such as what web server software is being run. It is not specified in the HTML or HTTP standards.