# Add custom $_POST before submitting form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

First of all, sorry if this is a duplicate. I've looked and seen some solutions but none worked. I've been trying to do this simple thing for like 3 hours with no result.

I'd have this html:

```
<form method="post" action="?c=Logo&action=save" id="form">
    <!-- some inputs -->
    <img src="" data-filename="new-logo.png">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here I'd like to modify the form so my php file will recognise $_POST['new-logo'].

```
// $_POST['new-logo'] =  $('img').data('filename')
$logo = new Logo($_POST['new-logo']); 
$logo->save();
```

I guess I should use the jQuery function $.post() but somehow I can't manage. Thank you all for your help :-)

**SOLUTION**
Finally since I found a very simple solution. Since I want my data to be processed in my php file, I simply added an `<input type="hidden">` and modified its value with JS :-)

Comment: you need to put enctype attribut on form tag  ```<form ... method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">``` see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work and here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You should post what you tried, even if it didn't work. Then we at least have a starting point for trying to show you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the data array from scratch like this:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $(this).attr('action'),
       data: {key1:"value", key2:"value2"},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           //do success stuff here
       },
       error: function() {
           //do error stuff here.
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: sir, why did you copy my entier answer O.o

Comment: I didn't. look closer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a hidden input.

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $(this).append($("<input>", {
        type: "hidden",
        name: "new-logo",
        value: $(this).find("img").data("filename")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to you're post request like this :

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);

    var datastring = $form.serializeArray();
    datastring.push({name:'new-logo', value:$form.find('img').data('filename')});

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $form.attr('action'),
       data: datastring,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
           // do what ever you want with the server response
       },
       error: function() {
           alert('error handing here');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        $logo = new Logo($_POST['new-logo']);
```

Is "new Logo" a function or something? Pretty sure that can't have a space.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Comment: Sorry m8. Never really worked with php classes and such. :/