# UpdateRecipientSignatureImage API how to construct the request body?

Tags: docusignapi

Seems like there is no documentation on how to construct a request body or payload for UpdateRecipientSignatureImage API. I need to use this API to try update a signature for a accountless signer.

Please, if anyone had experience with this API help me.
Thank you!
Ref.: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/updateRecipientSignatureImage/#definitions

Comment: The request body is a gif, png, jpeg, or bmp file that is less than 200KB in size.

Comment: but how do you add a gif, png, jpeg, or bmp file to the request body?
There seems to be plenty of ways, but in which format does Docusign accept the image? (like a form data or an attachment file or else?)

Comment: It would depend on what programming language and any sdks or libraries you are using. Generally speaking though the body is just the raw bytes of the file and you set the Content-Type of the HTTP header to let the server know what kind of data it is.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28193031/4985580)

Comment: I am using the official Docusign PHP SDK. I think I understand a bit more.
Thanks by the way for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Include the image as the body of the Put request:

1. Set the Content-Type header. Eg `image/jpeg`, `image/png`, etc
2. Set the body of the PUT request to be the binary version of the image data.

Comment: I am using the Docusign official PHP SDK. Can you elaborate a bit more in details on how to "Set the body of the PUT request to be the binary version of the image data."?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the SDK, I call the API directly. I don't know if the SDK supports this API method. Please file an issue against the github repository.