# IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument with url

Tags: python, flask

I  am newbie in python and i am trying to open an localhost with write mode 
but i got following errors

```
with io.open('http:\\localhost:3000\\assets\\i18n\\locale-ru.json', 'w') as outfile:
```

`IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http:\\localhost:3000\\assets\\i18n\\locale-ru.json'`

Here is a piece of code:

```
 with io.open('http://localhost:3000//assets//i18n//locale-ru.json', 'w') as outfile:
  str_ = json.dumps(data_ru,
                    indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                    separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
  outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))
```

Comment: Just a note, you have only one slash after `http:\`.

Comment: with io.open('http:/localhost:3000//assets//i18n//locale-ru.json', 'w') as outfile:
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http:/localhost:3000//assets//i18n//locale-ru.json'

Comment: still got  error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open), the `io.open` function only reads a local file given a file path. Considering you're trying to read from a http url, I guess a better tools might be [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: getting struggle with reguests documentation, i would really appreciate if you send me with source code

Comment: what about urllib.urlopen in Python 2.7

Comment: ` with urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:3000//assets/i18n//locale-kg.json', 'w') as outfile:
      str_ = json.dumps(data_kg,
                        indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                        separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
      outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))`

Comment: As far as I know, to update a file via HTTP you have to send a POST or a PUT request with a file on your local, just like you upload a file to some website. So if I wanted to update a file via an URL, I would firstly download it to my local, then do changes on it, and finally upload the file back. As for file uploading, you could refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791188/2191173 for details.