# Getting file modified date on upload

Tags: python, flask

I am building a simple web app where users can upload a picture with Flask-WTF. I would like to get the last modified date of the uploaded file, something like using `os.path.getmtime(im_path)` but on the output of the form.

Comment: where should that date/time come from?  a browser wouldn't normally include that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660740/1358308  maybe you could parse the [EXIF data](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/69964/33980) in the photo instead?

Comment: Thanks Sam. I tried parsing the EXIF tags but it came up empty. So that information (last modified date) is not sent when uploading a file?

Comment: you might be able to coerce the browser into giving it to you, but you'd need to do something client side (i.e. javascript) in order to get it