# How to upload file through HTTP protocol with C++?

Tags: c++, spring-boot, http, http-protocols

I'm going to upload files with C++, to a Java spring boot web server.

I constructed the protocol looks like below (in plain text):

```
POST /gallery/multimedia/uploadvideo HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.133:8981
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------boundary1804289383
Connection: keep-alive

--------boundary1804289383
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.mp4"
Content-Length: 948611
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

... binary video data here ...

--------boundary1804289383--
```

The server side is Java spring boot server, interface defined as below:

```
@PostMapping("uploadvideo")
public ResultVo uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file);
```

While posting file, the server responses with code 400, and complains that

> Required request part 'file' is not present

However with a simple HTML page, file uploaded successfully, the HTML page listed below:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
            action="http://192.168.0.133:8981/gallery/multimedia/uploadvideo">
            <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
            <input id="submit" value="submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What do I miss?

---

Edit:

I've tried Postman/Chrome console/curl, all these tools only print the request looks like:

```
# this is from curl
POST /gallery/multimedia/uploadvideo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: 192.168.0.133:8981
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 187
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------3c653d03b97f
```

How should I construct the file part? Any ideas?

Comment: [Postman](https://www.postman.com) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) are your best friends for such problems.

Comment: Check this answer on how to find out what your browser sends to the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791188/2527795

Comment: Where is the actual c++ part within your question/code snippets? Did I miss something fundamental here?

Comment: Look at what the request sent from the browser and from your c++ program looks like, and check what is different.

Comment: You can use curl with `--trace -` to see exactly what it sends and compare that to what your program is sending.

Comment: The RFC says *The multipart/form-data media type does not support any MIME header fields in parts other than Content-Type, Content-Disposition, and (in limited circumstances) Content-Transfer-Encoding. Other header fields MUST NOT be included and MUST be ignored*, and also *Senders SHOULD NOT generate any parts with a Content-Transfer-Encoding header field*. Just sayin'.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have tried Postman, which does not show the http protocol of file part. I will try Wireshark, thanks.

Comment: @Secundi the c++ part is all about string concatenation, to construct the http protocol text, and write it to socket by system call write, which is point of this question. "C++" in the title points to the question how to construct the protocol to post file by not using third party http library.

Comment: @super I did that already, in Postman and Chrome console, neither of them show http protocol of file part , only protocol before boundary line.

Comment: @strupo I will try, thanks for your advice.

Comment: You may want to use some existing C++ or C libraries such as [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). You should read a good book about HTTP

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for @strupo 's suggestion.

By turning on `--trace` option of `curl` and viewing the output log file, I finally fixed this problem.

In `curl`, it posts file by several packets:

The header:

```
POST /gallery/multimedia/uploadvideo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: 192.168.0.133:8981
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 13602  # you have to calculate content length first
Expect: 100-continue   # very important line
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------3c653d03b97f
```

then it waits for server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100
```

after server responsed code 100, it sends data content, the form-data header goes first:

```
--------3c653d03b97f
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.mp4"
Content-Length: 6640
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

and file content follows, (in my case, a large memory is allocated, read from file and write to socket in once), and next file.

Finally the protocol should finished with boundary line:

```
--------3c653d03b97f--
```

The `Content-Length` should include all bytes being sent after header. The `boundary` should be prefixed with `--` in file part. Also the `\r\n` everywhere should be noticed.