# Should I use multipart/form-data or text/csv content type for uploading CSV file to server?

Tags: csv, file-upload, backend

I'm working on a back-end feature that involves processing CSV files uploaded by users. Most tutorials I've found so far suggest that I should read that CSV file through a multipart request.

https://www.appcoda.com/restful-api-tutorial-how-to-upload-files-to-server/

[How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work/)

However, as far as I know, multipart requests involve a boundary and only make sense when we need to send different kinds of payload over the same request. For CSV file uploading, all I need is to send a byte stream over the request body (with the appropriate text/csv content type).

I'm not sure if there is any specific reason that people use and suggest multipart requests for uploading files?

Answer (score 1):

if you use text/csv your request body should be raw text (like with json) like
"1,2,3
4,5,6"
But if you want upload file, content-type should say about it.
so, in that case i recomend to use multipart/form-data when uploading any type of files