# Best approach for web service call with 10MB payload

Tags: java, web-services, networking, architecture

I'm designing a system that will need to make WS calls to an endpoint, passing a payload of approximately 10MB in size (uncompressed).
I'm a bit clueless as I've only dealt with ordinary WS calls so appreciate any advice on the best practices (TCP/UDP, REST/GRPC, compression, etc).

Some context:

- Latency and throughput are not critical
- I'll be using Java for the call, receiver will be python
- We have control over the receiver end too, so we can ask them to accommodate our solution

Comment: 10M is not huge. I would keep it simple. A regular HTTP POST with binary data using gzip compression (built into most HTTP clients and servers, so no special code) should do the job.

Comment: Can you send the data as a file using multi-part form data encoding as explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35091777/734744 In that example the client is a standard browser. You java code needs to emulate that behavior. Otherwise you can send data in normal POST body as name=value format.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with IoT? If not then first comment holds true