# Uploading in bulk in form-data using postman?

Tags: json, postman, backend, bulkinsert

```json
    {
        "addStandard": [
            {   
                "attachments": ["file1,file2,file3"],   
                "organization": "3", 
                "designationNubmer": "3", 
                "recognition": "3", 
                "title": "3", 
                "generalUse": "3",
                // "applicant_info_id": 1,
                // "attachmentsId": 1
            },
            {
                "organization": "4", 
                "designationNubmer": "4", 
                "recognition": "4", 
                "title": "4", 
                "generalUse": "4",
                // "applicant_info_id": 1,
                //"attachmentsId": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

how can I bulk add the above JSON object in the form-data? The attachments are the actual array of file object.

[image]

I don't have any idea of how can I bulk add the attachments file objects in the form data?
I know the above screenshot is wrong, as I've also not mentioned the "addStandards".

Comment: If you want to parse the JSON, load the files and sent them, then you are asking more than Postman can do. You would have to load the files (which I do NOT believe Postman is capable of, and attach them. You might need to use a real scripting or programming language to complete what you want. also I think you need to use `multipart/form-data` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work ) Postman is not the right hammer for this torx screw

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't.

If you want to parse the JSON, load the files and sent them, then you are asking more than Postman can do.

You would have to load the files (which I do NOT believe Postman is capable of, and attach them. Also you need to use `multipart/form-data` (see [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work) ) Postman is not the right hammer for this torx screw.

You need to use a real scripting or programming language to complete what you want.

I have made a simple python script which will solve your issue:

Given this layout:
[image: file layout]

and this instruction.json:

```json
{
    "addStandard": [
        {
            "attachments": [
                "file1.txt",
                "file2.txt",
                "file3.txt"
            ],
            "organization": "3",
            "designationNumber": "3",
            "recognition": "3",
            "title": "3",
            "generalUse": "3"
        },
        {
            "attachments": [
                "file4.png"
            ],
            "organization": "4",
            "designationNumber": "4",
            "recognition": "4",
            "title": "4",
            "generalUse": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

This Python script will parse the JSON, load each file, detect the mime type, and upload it.

```py
import requests
import json
import mimetypes

#file upload using https://pypi.org/project/requests/ based on json input

#mimetype = 'text/plain'

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'


# Load json with instructions
instruction_file = open('payload/instructions.json')
instruction_data = json.load(instruction_file)
instruction_file.close()

# Parse each payload
for instruction in instruction_data['addStandard']:
    files = {}
    payload = instruction
    # Parse  filelist
    for filename in instruction["attachments"]:
        #print(filename)
        filepath = 'payload/'+filename
        mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        file_payload = open(filepath, 'rb')
        files[filename] =  (filename, file_payload, mimetype, {'Expires': '0'})
        #file_payload.close() # this doesn't work! TODO: gather file handles and close them after sending
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
    #print(r.status_code)
    #TODO: close file handles here, before reading the next instruction set
```

Note that I think there is a memory leak, since we call ´open()´ but never close the files. I have added comments to this effect This is no issue for small lists and files, but if you are uploading mpgs it will become an issue. Your question does not state any file extension, hence I have assumed smaller files...