# Bash internal commands from C program (Ubuntu v/s MacOS)

Tags: c, bash, macos, ubuntu

The following code successfully lists the contents of current directory on Ubuntu bash and MacOS bash.

```
int main() {
    char* args[3];
    args[0] = "ls";
    args[1] = NULL;
    args[2] = NULL;
    execvp(args[0], args);
    return 0;
}
```

The following code doesn't print anything on Ubuntu bash but prints `ls is /bin/ls` on MacOS bash.

```
int main() {
    //pid_t pid = fork();
    char * args[3];
    args[0] = "type";
    args[1] = "ls";
    args[2] = NULL;
    //if (!pid) 
    execvp(args[0], args);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `type` on Ubuntu bash directly, it prints `ls is hashed (/bin/ls)`.

The difference is that `type` is a bash internal command while `ls` is not. But why does bash on Ubuntu behave differently from that on MacOS?

Ubuntu bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

MacOS bash version: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`

Judging purely by version numbers (which may be an incorrect thing to do), older version prints output correctly while newer version doesn't?

Comment: What is your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))? It probably is different on MacOSX. Or the directories there are not the same. Perhaps MacOSX has some `/usr/bin/type`  thing but Ubuntu has not any such stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to test against failure of `execvp`. Try at least to code:

```
if (execvp(args[0], args)) {
   fprintf(stderr, "execvp %s failed: %s\n",
           args[0], strerror(errno));
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Probably on your Ubuntu `execvp` of `type` fails. Perhaps MacOSX has some `/usr/bin/type` or whatever is found in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Read *carefully* the documentation of [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) on *both* systems. Consider also using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on Linux to understand what is going on (you can find a [similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925978/841108) for MacOSX).

Notice that `execvp` works only on *executable* files (not on shell builtin commands)

Comment: execvp type failed: No such file or directory. You are right: MacOS gives  `/usr/bin/type` when I run `whereis type` while Ubuntu gives `type:`.

Comment: So is there any way to execute `type` on Ubuntu from a C program?

Comment: You can run `bash -c 'type %'` but that's obviously specific to your shell. (So in fact is `/usr/bin/type` on MacOS; it runs `/bin/sh` and executes `builtin type ${1+"$@"}`.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `bash` in your question. That is to say, nothing in the execution of that program has anything to do with `bash`.

`execvp` is, effectively, a system call which has the effect (if it succeeds, which should not be taken for granted) of replacing the current execution environment with a new process image, loading the executable from the file indicated as the first argument. The OS neither needs or seeks assistance from `bash` to execute the program.

If you want to use `bash`, you need to ask the OS to run bash. This might be useful if you want to run a `bash` built-in command:

```
char* args[] = { "bash", "-c", "type ls", 0};
execvp(args[0], args);
```

But since you are not invoking `bash`, you rely on the existence of an external command utility named `type`. And it is the existence or not of that utility which leads to the different behaviour. It has nothing to do with `bash` or any other shell.